# Starting service with su -c "start vendor.diag-router" in SeLinux enforced mode gives error

Tags: terminal, selinux, services, background-process, init.d

While being in enforced mode i ran below in Termux:

```
su -c "start vendor.diag-router"
```

which gave me output:

> Unable to start service 'vendor.diag-router' See dmesg for error
> reason.

In logs i can see only below related entry but not any other selinux denial or anything:

> 02-07 14:35:41.539  1758  1758 W libc    : Unable to set property
> "ctl.start" to "vendor.diag-router": error code: 0x20

I have tried researching this error but didn't find anything needed.

**All i want is:**

- start that service in runtime via terminal.
- while being in enforced mode.
- without making any modifications to selinux policies and build rom again but i am ready to patch selinux policies in runtime with *magiskpolicy* or *ksud sepolicy* tool.

**My findings:**

- I can start that service in permissive mode without any issue.(but that i don't want)
- I have logged selinux denials while doing above step and
  later tried patching selinux policy then tried starting that service but still it is giving same error in enforced mode.

**Phone OS:** Android 13